# How can you write rails specs that shows a forced redirection to https?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I want to show a behavior that basically shows that the path "/" works on an http domain, and going to the path "/users/sign_in" forces a redirection to https.  How can you spec this out?  Does this belong in controller, request, or routing specs?

The spec would look like:

```
describe "https redirection" do
  context "when http" do
    it "forces a permanent redirect to /users/sign_in on https when path is /users/sign_in" do
    end
    it "returns status of 200 when path is /"
    end
  end
  context "when https" do
    it "returns status of 200 when path is /users/sign_in"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `request.env['HTTPS'] = 'on'` to activate https.

In integration tests you can check if http is active with `current_url.should match /^https:/`

Comment: I merely added the `request.env['HTTPS'] = 'on'` to your spec. I would do a controller spec using that variable to activate the https and then verify the result.

Comment: but how would you show that the domain started at http then was ended at https after the redirect?

Comment: Now I understand what you want. Check the second line of the new solution. It must be an integration test.